# error: The type oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthConsumer cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, android, oauth, buildpath

I am attempting to import some previously built code into my workspace, however I am being given this error and cannot find a working solution:

`The type oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthConsumer cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`

I have added all jars to the build path and rebuilt the code but none of these seem to work, has anyone encountered this issue before that can offer some suggestions? any help would go a long way thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please add to your build path the library [here](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/downloads/detail?name=signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar). This is signpost core lib. The error will then go away.

After it builds, when run it throws another error: "Class not found: OAuthFlowApp". To remove this error, please set your build path as shown in attached image [image: Build Path snapshot]